# Ansible:how to adapt the output format of map (with extract) filters

Tags: ansible, jinja

I am trying to extract the IP addresses of the hosts that are part of two groups and use them in a .xml config file.

The problem I'm facing here is the output generated by the expression used into the jinja template. What I want to achieve is an output like `10.3.5.1,10.3.5.2,10.3.5.2` but instead of this I'm obtaining something like `[u'10.3.5.1],[u'10.3.5.2],[u'10.3.5.2]`.

This is the expression used into the jinja template:

```
<member1>{{ (groups['group_one']+groups['group_two']) | map('extract',hostvars,'ansible_ip_addresses') | list | unique | join(',') }}</member1>
```

I have also tried some other filters but I could not get the expected result.

What filters should I use for this? (I couldn't find the right ones)

Comment: What is this fact `ansible_ip_addresses` that you are using? It doesn't appear to be a standard fact. Where did it come from? How did you set it?

Comment: this is an ansible fact collected from a windows host. I am using ansible 2.4.2.0

Comment: That's interesting. What does it look like? I have no Windows hosts, and Linux hosts have no such fact.

Comment: "ansible_ip_addresses": [
            "10.3.5.1"
        ]

Comment: Hm, OK, that seems reasonable. Linux hosts get two different facts, `ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` and `ansible_all_ipv6_addresses`, which are also just lists of strings. These appear to work in this template. So I'm not sure what exactly is going on here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41521816/2947502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ansible_ip_addresses` is a list, so you have a list (of hosts) with nested lists (with ip addresses).

You probably want to flatten it before applying `unique` and `join`:

```
{{ (groups['group_one']+groups['group_two']) | map('extract',hostvars,'ansible_ip_addresses') | list | sum(start=[]) | unique | join(',') }}
```

This will make a flat list with single ip-address as element, than take unique items and join them with comma.